# Can't delete OData service from "/n/iwfnd/maint_service"

Tags: netweaver, sap-gateway

This is a custom OData gateway service that I imported from a transport from a different system.

If I go to `/n/iwfnd/maint_service` and try to delete the service it says:

```
Service cannot be deleted, delete ICF Node first
```

If I try to delete the ICF Node I get:

```
ICF node 'ZAPMEXTERNALDATA' could not be deleted.
Reason: 'Node is not in original system'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I got it resolved.

To delete the service:

1. Goto TCODE: SE03
2. Choose IWSG and IWOM with “ZAPM*” as shown below.  ( the start of the name of your service )
   You can see in the image below that they are "SAP Gateway: Service" and "SAP Gateway: Model M..."

[image]

3. Click execute.
4. For each of the two object directory entries change them to the current system that you are in and save.  In this example, I am in RS9 and want to delete the service.

   [image]

   [image]
5. After this you should be able to delete the service from /n/iwfnd/maint_service

Answer (score 0):

I assume you should do this via transport. As stated in SAP Note [2244649](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0002244649),

> Any changes you need to make should be done through transport only.
>   i.e. If you want to delete a service which was transported from
>   development system, then you need to delete the service in development
>   system and then transport that transport request so that the changes
>   get reflected in quality system or production system.

The same rules apply to nodes.

Comment: This makes me think maybe we are doing something fundamentally wrong.  We have created two packages, a business suite package and a gateway package that we are planning to ship to customers.  When we exported these packages and import them into another system we get the service created as well.  If a customer wanted to remove our software, we would have to remove the service in our system first?

Comment: Exactly! BTW, the same rules apply to any Z object (program, table, search-help, etc.). You cannot just delete anything from QA or PROD.

Comment: You said you export packages and import them to client. Does your client lacks DEV-system where the development should take place?

Comment: One thing I don't understand.  We are developing something in house and "shipping" it to various clients  ( hopefully :) ).   But I'm surprised that after we "ship" it, it can't be removed.  Is there something wrong with our approach?  Is there something we should be doing before shipping it, or packaging it up?  Is it proper to be shipping Z objects?  Our client does have DEV systems.